# Why $tan \Theta _{i} = d_{i}2^{-i}$?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

I was reading about the cordic algorithm for calculating trigonometric functions and I saw this:

$\tan \Theta _{i} = d_{i}2^{-i}$ with $d_{i} = -1$.

Supposing that $\tan \Theta _{i}$ is chosen between 0 and 45 degrees.

Comment: put math expressions between $ signs

Comment: Sorry, Now is legible

Comment: You have just mentioned what you have read. What is your doubt or question about it?

Comment: How can I check out that's true? It's kind of weird

Comment: @Rise could you help me pls?

Answer (score 1):

That is the *definition* of those values.

There are many articles on the web
about cordic.
Here is a typical one:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC

Then look at the references.

Comment: is there any way to prove they are real?

Comment: If $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$, then $-1 < \tan(x) < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Without some restriction on $\Theta_i$ this is not true.  In particular, $\tan 22.5^\circ=\sqrt 2 -1\ \gt 0$  I think you really have a sum over $i$.  Please get your question right.